# Should i return all authorities in `spring-authorization-server`?

Tags: spring-security

I have a question about OAuth2 with Spring Security. Could you give some help? Thanks!

When i use `spring-security-oauth2` which is deprecated now, i have

1. A `messaging-client` with all four OAuth2 grant types.
2. A user with `a1` `a2` `a3` ... authorities.

   ```
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("messaging-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "client_credentials", "password")
                .scopes("message.read", "message.write")
                .secret("{noop}secret")
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:8080/authorized");
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService users() throws Exception {
        User.UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(users.username("user1").password("password").roles("USER").build());
        manager.createUser(users.username("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN").authorities("a1",
                "a2","a3","a4","a5","a5","a6","a7","a8").build());
        return manager;
    }
   ```

Then i request token and get bellow:

```
{
"access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IllQejQwR1NjRzZ5NDNnZjM4TmxUVVJobFVwRHdOUlZydVNkQVFYTUVXMnM9In0.eyJleHAiOjE2MjEzNjg4NjEsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiYTEiLCJhMiIsImEzIiwiYTQiLCJhNSIsImE2IiwiYTciLCJhOCJdLCJqdGkiOiI1MTdhOWQyYy1kMDZjLTRiNzAtODAwMC00NjhhNjEyNGY0MzkiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJtZXNzYWdpbmctY2xpZW50Iiwic2NvcGUiOlsibWVzc2FnZS5yZWFkIiwibWVzc2FnZS53cml0ZSJdfQ.d4c9p3RzgdC983cJqeGHNDOFr-pcTxCWMKEIgyTP9GHjMENHzQG2TQoUAXhXlzRJZn_e-QHVPCTphh4kG9RWBLYEM_8mpO3YY7l4pFs9JxV2H8w9L2exVzzgUAE4m4yT6-2-yrRYbQIBXuVLXPxylUaG__dNbr7txkhg-HeX2lDE7vK0kpT1wQqmWU-6G7RZzwZuUy1aYiwAkRILCdn6yP9h8D2HhHVzwNSDBMqowN7waZFBfpDYHzQsGiasY1NfiCJe6beEANhvNSeFd3FBwqZM32fVEX8I5jtgnRJZgbclBe6LJXwtNSxjtjfIQThuTML-EJ2pPMvqnSXDnPJLdg",
"token_type": "bearer",
"refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IllQejQwR1NjRzZ5NDNnZjM4TmxUVVJobFVwRHdOUlZydVNkQVFYTUVXMnM9In0.eyJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsInNjb3BlIjpbIm1lc3NhZ2UucmVhZCIsIm1lc3NhZ2Uud3JpdGUiXSwiYXRpIjoiNTE3YTlkMmMtZDA2Yy00YjcwLTgwMDAtNDY4YTYxMjRmNDM5IiwiZXhwIjoxNjIzOTE3NjYxLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJhMSIsImEyIiwiYTMiLCJhNCIsImE1IiwiYTYiLCJhNyIsImE4Il0sImp0aSI6IjA1ZWRiNGEwLWQ5ZjMtNGVjOS05MzRkLWQ1MjljZmYzMzRlYiIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6Im1lc3NhZ2luZy1jbGllbnQifQ.TzZARXqaiKPkKc53F3jRX57ObHoleZS9kNrAh_3dkvd4u6UF9vtfjFkaS2zP1uH4alE5U6ayLcu6k3OinLtoTkSuEvE5MbJ0ccffcLmNcRIw7DuoRyoT7n-hzTJ3z78be4iWlIxmKswyIUAl2vE2xB9IQwKjD_HOH5WnA2Fu5_OuiCNsXZZyRGbUVXqFM91wJe7iQsqjzzjhynzVReFmtblZ-hGR7a6Bo9OJj1wSsTlu8rbmLamqijCXrlj-RnLxyS1Hv9LWwKEwey7Mo2fExBQT0o2iNqtQk987DhUprln98IWxn-8H2T09cPJLjDyOg5vv-Q6GjCeKrqcVGkEVmQ",
"expires_in": 43199,
"scope": "message.read message.write",
"jti": "517a9d2c-d06c-4b70-8000-468a6124f439"
```

}

It's good.

Then i decode the `access_token`, i got these.

```
{
 "exp": 1621368861,
 "user_name": "admin",
 "authorities": [
  "a1",
  "a2",
  "a3",
  "a4",
  "a5",
  "a6",
  "a7",
  "a8"
 ],
 "jti": "517a9d2c-d06c-4b70-8000-468a6124f439",
 "client_id": "messaging-client",
 "scope": [
  "message.read",
  "message.write"
 ]
}
```

Works fine.

But i want to learn more about `spring-security-oauth2`, there is no document.

Since spring-security-oauth2 is deprecated, i turned to spring-authorization-server now.

But `password` grant type has not supported yes. And i don't know `spring-authorization-server` will support it or not. So i want to contribute code.

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        OAuth2PasswordAuthenticationToken passwordAuthenticationToken =
                (OAuth2PasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken clientPrincipal =
                getAuthenticatedClientElseThrowInvalidClient(passwordAuthenticationToken);
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = clientPrincipal.getRegisteredClient();

        if (!registeredClient.getAuthorizationGrantTypes().contains(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD)) {
            throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(new OAuth2Error(OAuth2ErrorCodes.UNAUTHORIZED_CLIENT));
        }

        String username = passwordAuthenticationToken.getUsername();
        String password = passwordAuthenticationToken.getPassword();

        //validate the resource owner password credentials
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if (!Objects.nonNull(userDetails) || !this.passwordEncoder.matches(password, userDetails.getPassword())){
            throwInvalidClient();
        }

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = userDetails.getAuthorities();
        ......
```

Next step is generate `access_token`, should i put all authorities to `access_token`? What if user has a lot of `authorities`? Which claim should i put?

Comment: It's awesome that you want to contribute code related to supporting this feature. I'm thinking this could be a pretty big discussion. Would you be interested in creating a branch over in [spring-authorization-server](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server) and opening a draft PR we can use to discuss more?

Comment: I found an issue about [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server/pull/115) .It seems  that `spring-authorization-server` will not support `Resource Owner Password Grant`.

Comment: Sorry I misread your post and was thinking "client credentials" grant type. I believe that is correct. See the [OAuth 2.1 spec, Section 12](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-01#section-12). That grant type is considered insecure. For more information, see [OAuth 2.0 Security Best Current Practice](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-16#section-2.4).